# Python Adding multipe columns to dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I and trying to create a dataframe with 9 different columns from 1 column coming from source dataframe. I cant figure out what I did wrong. The first works always but then the rest dont. I have tried Orange and Yellow first and the data gets inserted but the second command and rest get inserted as nan.

```
lastdate = '10/23/2021'
column_names = ["Red", "Orange", "Yellow","Green","Blue","Violet","Black","Brown"]
dftcolorAgg = pd.DataFrame(columns = column_names)
dftcolorAgg['Red'] = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Red') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
dftcolorAgg['Orange'] = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Orange') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
dftcolorAgg['Yellow'] = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Yellow') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
dftcolorAgg['Green'] = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Green') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
dftcolorAgg['Blue'] = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Blue') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
dftcolorAgg['Indigo'] = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Indigo') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
dftcolorAgg['Violet'] = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Violet') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
dftcolorAgg['Black'] = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Black') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
dftcolorAgg['Brown'] = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Brown') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
```

Second approach

```
red = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Red') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
orange = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Orange') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
yellow = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Yellow') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
green = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Green') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
blue = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Blue') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
indigo = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Indigo') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
violet = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Violet') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
black = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Black') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height
brown = df[ (df['Color'] == 'Brown') & (df['Date'] == lastdate)].Height

dftcolorAgg = pd.concat([red, orange,yellow,green,blue,indigo,violet,black,brown], axis=1)
```

Second approach just adds nans no values. Also each statement added 8 more rows so I ended up with 72 rows all nan

I would like to have each statement insert values into new data frame and all values be in the same 8 rows per column.

Here is some sample data

```
Date,color,Height
10/25/2021,red,15
10/25/2021,red,0
10/25/2021,red,15
10/25/2021,red,17.5
10/25/2021,red,4.5
10/25/2021,red,18
10/25/2021,red,9
10/25/2021,red,18
10/25/2021,orange,16
10/25/2021,orange,19.9
10/25/2021,orange,17.8
10/25/2021,orange,16
10/25/2021,orange,.1
10/25/2021,orange,6.5
10/25/2021,orange,13
10/25/2021,orange,0
10/25/2021,yellow,0
10/25/2021,yellow,10.9
10/25/2021,yellow,12
10/25/2021,yellow,18
10/25/2021,yellow,16.5
10/25/2021,yellow,16
10/25/2021,yellow,8
10/25/2021,yellow,14.6
```

Expected outcome

```
Red orange  yellow
15    16      0
0     19.9    10.9
15    17.8    12
17.5  16      18
4.5   .1      16.5
18    6.5     16
9     13      8
18    0       14.6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question is not clear how to handle the `Height` columns, i.e. which kind of aggregation must be applied.
Anyway, there are a couple of useful functions in pandas that can be used:
[pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

This example uses the pivot to create new columns from values in a column.

```
import pandas as pd

color = ['red','yellow','red','blue','blue']
height = range(len(colors))
df = pd.DataFrame({'color':color, 'height':height})

df.pivot(columns='color')


    height
color   blue    red     yellow
0   NaN     0.0     NaN
1   NaN     NaN     1.0
2   NaN     2.0     NaN
3   3.0     NaN     NaN
4   4.0     NaN     NaN
```

As you can see the pivoted values create new columns based on the values of the columns named `color`.

Another approach can be to use indexes and the [unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html?highlight=unstack#pandas.DataFrame.unstack) function.

### Update

With given data, the `pivot` approach is this:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO
strm = StringIO("""Date,color,Height
10/25/2021,red,15
10/25/2021,red,0
10/25/2021,red,15
10/25/2021,red,17.5
10/25/2021,red,4.5
10/25/2021,red,18
10/25/2021,red,9
10/25/2021,red,18
10/25/2021,orange,16
10/25/2021,orange,19.9
10/25/2021,orange,17.8
10/25/2021,orange,16
10/25/2021,orange,.1
10/25/2021,orange,6.5
10/25/2021,orange,13
10/25/2021,orange,0
10/25/2021,yellow,0
10/25/2021,yellow,10.9
10/25/2021,yellow,12
10/25/2021,yellow,18
10/25/2021,yellow,16.5
10/25/2021,yellow,16
10/25/2021,yellow,8
10/25/2021,yellow,14.6""")

df = pd.read_csv(strm, sep=",")
df['idx'] = df.groupby('color')['color'].cumcount()
df.pivot(columns=['color'], index='idx', values='Height').reset_index(drop=True)
    
#alternative
#pd.pivot_table(df, columns=['color'], index='idx').reset_index(drop=True)


# output
color   orange  red     yellow
idx             
0   16.0    15.0    0.0
1   19.9    0.0     10.9
2   17.8    15.0    12.0
3   16.0    17.5    18.0
4   0.1     4.5     16.5
5   6.5     18.0    16.0
6   13.0    9.0     8.0
7   0.0     18.0    14.6
```

Comment: Thank you Glauco, code did not work i still get nan all colors have 8 values. No nans are present yet I get numbers spread across table.

Comment: please provide df values, it is hard to imagine how they are organized

Comment: Added some sample data and expected output. I added date because its a filter on the actual table.

Comment: I've update my previous response with the solution